# Indexing matrix to get corresponding values for condition,store in a new matrix each time?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Sorry for the perhaps confusing title...

Basically I have a 3x3 matrix containing elevation angle, azimuth angle and range. I want to generate new matrices each time elevation >5 deg. There are usually about 5 segments that have this data and I want to separate each one into a new matrix.

I know how to index but not sure how to put this condition in...

Thanks

```
sat_tcs=llh2tcsT(sat_llh,station_llh);
```

sat_elev=atan2(sat_tcs(3,:),sqrt(sat_tcs(1,:).^2+sat_tcs(2,:).^2));
sat_azim=atan2(-sat_tcs(2,:),sat_tcs(1,:));
range=sqrt(sat_tcs(1,:).^2+sat_tcs(2,:).^2+sat_tcs(3,:).^2);`                                                             sat_elev(sat_elev < 5*deg2rad) = NaN;                                           sat_look_tcs=[sat_elev;sat_azim;range];

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're looking for -- do you have some samples of inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have some examples of the input and expected output, but taking a guess at what you mean I'd try this:

```
elevation_column = 3;
threshold = 5;
m = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 2 3];
n = m(m(:,elevation_column)>threshold,:);
```

This produces:

```
n =

     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

Comment: This is more or less what I mean but how do you include elevation itself to make another 3x3? Also, is there any way to generate a new matrix each time it changes? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really clear on what you're after. Can you update you question with an example of your starting data and a example of the desired result. Just do it add a code block like I've done in my answer. I don't think we'll be able to help you get to the answer with that kind of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I would post an image of my graph but supposedly I need reputation points for that..but it the elevation data looks almost sinusoidal and so it has regions over 5 deg and then falls again. I want to generate a new matrix for every set above this angle